# A proper subset of a set $S$ is equinumerous to $S$. Is this a contradiction?

Tags: set-theory

It is known that $nZ$ is a strict subset of $Z$, but we can construct an isomorphism between them, showing that they are equinumerous. How come a strict subset, which contains less element, is equinumerous to the larger set containing it? This phenomenon intuitively does not make much sense to me. Is it one of the prices of accepting the infinity axiom of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory?

Comment: Mapping $x\mapsto nx$ is a bijection between $\Bbb Z$ and $n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Working with infinity is frequently counterintuitive.  And, it used to be believed that if you stared to hard at infinity it would drive a person to madness.  Two infinite sets can have the same cardinality even though one is a proper subset of the other.

Comment: See so-called [Galileo's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_paradox): "a demonstration of one of the surprising properties of infinite sets."

Comment: So "the prices of accepting to "manage" mathematically the infinity" is that we have to give up some of our intuitions about "size" that we have developed dealing with finite collections.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you mean that to accept the existence of infinity, we just have to come to terms with this phenomenon?

Comment: More or less... This is what is needed **IF** we accept the treatment of infinity according to modern mathematical theory of sets.

Comment: Thank you for all comments made here. I think infinities make our lives much easier, so why not let them exist? Extending the notion of 'equal size' to infinite sets, which might cause some counter-intuitive phenomena, is a small price compared to the benefits we get out of having infinities.